# Integral Of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3\sin^2(\theta)+\frac{2r^{2}\cdot \sin(\theta)}{(r^2+1)^2}drd\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3\sin^2(\theta)+\frac{2r^{2}\cdot \sin(\theta)}{(r^2+1)^2}drd\theta$$
My main problem is how how to order it or to change variables that will make it more simple.
I would like to get some advice how to do that.
thanks!

Comment: Change the order of integration, that simplifies things a little.

Comment: The Maple command $$VectorCalculus:-int(r^3*sin(theta)^2+2*r^2*sin(theta)/(r^2+1)^3, [r, theta] = Rectangle(0 .. 2, 0 .. 2*Pi)) $$ outputs $4\pi .$

Answer (score 3):

First split the integral :

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3\sin^2(\theta)+\frac{2r^{2}\cdot \sin(\theta)}{(r^2+1)^2}drd\theta$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3\sin^2(\theta)drd\theta+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{2r^{2}\cdot \sin(\theta)}{(r^2+1)^2}drd\theta$$

Noticing that

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{2r^{2}\cdot \sin(\theta)}{(r^2+1)^2}drd\theta = (\int_{0}^{2}\frac{2r^{2}}{(r^2+1)^2}dr)\cdot (\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\theta) d\theta) = 0$$

So the result is just $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3 sin^2(\theta)drd\theta = 4 \cdot \int_0^{2\pi}sin^2(\theta)d\theta = 4\pi$$

Comment: You got your integral wrong, the _average_ of $\sin^2 \theta$ over the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is $\frac12$, the integral is not.

Comment: Oops you're right...

Comment: how you passed from the upper LHS to the RHS, how its r3sin2(θ)?

Comment: I splited the integral in two parts (each term of the sum).  
I'll update the answer to be clearer.